# Julia groupedDataFrame plot not showing in name

Tags: julia, julia-plots, dataframes.jl

I am attempting to plot in julialang a single plot with groupedDataFrames ... which isn't working if I just pass the array of traces... but for now I am just trying to put the `GroupKey` as a string under the X-Axis of a single plot... but it just shows `Trace0`.. Any ideas?

```
using PlotlyJS, DataFrames, Tables

gdf=groupby(subset_df, :company_name)

trace_array = []

for key in keys(gdf)
    println(key)
    push!(trace_array, box(y=gdf[key].target_price, name=key))
end

plot(trace_array[2])
```

[image]

Also tried

```
    company_name_str = unique(gdf[key].company_name)
    println(company_name_str)
    push!(trace_array, box(y=gdf[key].target_price, name=company_name_str))
```

no change in behavior

Comment: You haven't provided a minimal reproducible code and I really do not understand what is your exact expected output.

Comment: `name="blahblahblah"` properly sets the X-axis legend in the plot ... instead of `trace 0` like in this photo provided... When I attempt to use `GroupKey` .. as the X-Axis label as seen in the example code.. it doesn't work.

I will append some dummy code to create a dummy groupedDataFrame asap..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got your point. You're just missing an indexing in the optional `name` keyword argument: `key[1]`
I created a synthetic dataframe to reproduce it for you:

```
using PlotlyJS, DataFrames

df = DataFrame(
  g=["group1", "group1", "group1", "group2", "group2"],
  x=[1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
)

gdf = groupby(df, :g)

trace_array = []

for key in keys(gdf)
    push!(trace_array, box(y=gdf[key].x, name=key[1]))
end

plot(trace_array[1])
```

[image]

As you can see, the `group1` is shown on the x-axis.